# Accent words insensitive search

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table and columns collation is : `utf8_general_ci`, now when i try to look for the word `Supermarché` the MySQL command return me empty result:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT libelle,activite,adresse,tel,lat,lng FROM etablissements where type = "Supermarché"');
```

However, when i looked for another word without accent in the same table (the same column's too), i got the result correctly.

Is there any thing to do with the MySQL table structure?

Comment: Is your SESSION als utf8? Try `SET NAMES utf8;`and then retry your query.

Comment: do you mean to make an sql query on my table `etablissements` : `update etablissements set libelle utf8` and the same for all columns?

Comment: No. In your database connection FIRST run `SET NAMES utf8;` , then run your original query.

Comment: i use `mysqli`, how to write it please, i saw an example like this: `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of your PHP file should match the MySQL client encoding. Probably what's happening is that the é in your source code is not getting correctly to the database. If your source code is encoded in UTF-8 you should call

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");  or  mysqli::set_charset("utf8");
```

or if you use the old MySQL API:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

This has to be done once per connection, preferably just after creating it.

Another possibility is substituting the é with escape codes so that you'll always know what will be sent to the database:

```
"Supermarch\xe9"        # for connections in latin1
"Supermarch\xc3\xa9"    # for connections in utf8
```

Comment: i use`mysqli`, so would it be like this: `$this->db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_psw, $db_name)or die ("error connection to sql");
         mysqli_set_charset("utf8");`  if so, i got this warning: `Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: I had a small mistake there, with the mysqli OO interface it'd be `$this->db->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: Yes, but nothing has changed: `$this->db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_psw, $db_name)or die ("error connection to sql");
        $this->db->set_charset("utf8");`, always, the words with accents arn't retrieved :(

Comment: Sounds like there could be a problem with the existing data. What does this return? `SELECT CHARSET(type), HEX(type) FROM etablissements where type LIKE "Supermarch%" LIMIT 1`